# Exchange Server 2013 to 2016 Migration error

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, exchange-2016, microsoft, exchange-migration

I'm currently facing an issue during an Exchange Server database migration process from Exchange 2013 to Exchange 2016 and could really use some assistance. The migration process is failing with the following error:

***Error: MigrationTransientException: MapiExceptionMdbOffline: Unable to get mailbox information. ‎(hr=0x80004005, ec=1142)‎ Diagnostic context: Lid: 49384 Lid: 51176 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 40680 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 43980 Lid: 58295 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 50103 Lid: 48311 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 43959 Lid: 60343 StoreEc: 0x476 --> MapiExceptionMdbOffline: Unable to get mailbox information. ‎(hr=0x80004005, ec=1142)‎ Diagnostic context: Lid: 49384 Lid: 51176 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 40680 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 43980 Lid: 58295 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 50103 Lid: 48311 StoreEc: 0x476 Lid: 43959 Lid: 60343 StoreEc: 0x476***

This error suggests that the migration process is unable to access mailbox information due to the database being offline. I've attempted several troubleshooting steps, including checking the database status, ensuring Exchange services are running, verifying network connectivity, and reviewing permissions, but the issue persists.
Also tried enabling MAPI over HTTP: ***Set-OrganizationConfig -MapiHttpEnabled $true***

Has anyone encountered this error before, or does anyone have insights on additional steps I can take to resolve this? I'm particularly interested in understanding the significance of the error codes (ec=1142, StoreEc: 0x476) and if they point towards a specific direction for troubleshooting.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I would focus on the transient part. And the inability to connect. Is this something that should work 100% and is accessible sub millisecond access on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like databases might be in a dismounted state. If yes, please mount the database first and retry the migration.
There seems to be a similar case here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1523568/(hr-0x80004005-ec-1142)-when-trying-to-migrate-exc